# woocommerce update cart function refreshes page to the wrong domain

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using woocommerce and have run into some problems with the update cart function.

The cart can be updated to account for quantity changes of items but immediately after a pressing the 'update cart' button the page refreshes to show the wrong page, which says "Your cart is currently empty."

ex:
click "update cart" button > alpha.example.com/cart

what it should do:
click "update cart" button > businessname.com/cart

This problem occurs because the current domain is not the primary domain and is just a redirect. The current config is installed on alpha.example.com which redirects to businessname.com, so to my understanding those should both be the same page, but what occurs is an empty cart page is displayed.

Can that update cart button link to businessname.com/cart by editing the php?

If more clarity is needed feel free to ask. Thanks.